# how to bind data to this by destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript, object-destructuring

I wanna add new key and value to `this` object by `destructuring assignment`, but it falls in error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Let see my example, assume I have `obj` data object:

```
const obj = {
    'a':'1',
    'b':'2',
    'c':'3',
};
```

And now I wanna bind this data to `this` object, means we wanna have:

```
console.log(this.a); //=> "1"
```

So with destructuring assignment I write like these lines:

```
{
    a: this.a,
    b: this.b,
    c: this.c,
} = obj;
```

But it falls in error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I don't use `const`, `let` or `var` because the `this` object has already been declared. How I can reach my desire? is it possible by `destructuring assignment`?

Simply it is possible by normal assignment:

```
this.a = obj.a;
this.b = obj.b;
this.c = obj.c;
```

I just wanna right new and pretty `JavaScript` codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need parenthesis to distinguish the destruction object from a block statement.

```
({
    a: this.a,
    b: this.b,
    c: this.c,
} = obj);
```

Comment: `this` is the target object. it is the same as `this.a = obj.a;` etc.